# React, How to upload files to AWS S3 in react? using @aws-sdk/client-s3 npm package, can't find any good example for the same package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have tried other npm packages like react-s3 and react-aws-s3, but none of them works with the below code. I found this package [@aws-sdk/client-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-s3) but could not find any good example of configuring it.

```
import { uploadFile } from "react-s3";

 const config = {
  bucketName: "ABC",
  region: "DEF",
  accessKeyId: "GHI",
  secretAccessKey: "JKL",
};

export const uploadFileToS3 = async (file) => {
  try {
    const data = await uploadFile(file, config);
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return e;
  }
};

 const updateProfile = async (photo) => {
    uploadFileToS3(photo)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Before answer, I'm still working on my English.

i tried package `@aws-sdk/client-s3`.

Using S3Client and PutObjectCommand function, but it`s so simply example.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

function S3UploadSample() {
  const [selectFile, setSelectFile] = useState(null);

  const handleFileInput = (e) => {
    setSelectFile(e.target.files);
  };

  const handleUpload = async () => {
    const client = new S3Client({
      region: "/** your S3 region */",
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: "/** your S3 access key id */",
        secretAccessKey: "/** your S3 secret access key value */",
      },
    });

    const params = {
      Bucket: "/** your S3 bucket name */",
      Key: "/** object name in bucket */",
      Body: selectFile /** object body */,
    };

    const command = new PutObjectCommand(params);
    const data = await client.send(command);
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleFileInput} multiple></input>
      <button onClick={() => handleUpload(selectFile)}>Upload To S3</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default S3UploadSample;
```

I hope this code will help you.

Comment: Getting this error:             index.js:1 ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/config-resolver/dist-es/endpointsConfig/resolveEndpointsConfig.js 11:20
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:20)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   } = input;
|   return { ...input,
>     tls: input.tls ?? true,
|     endpoint: endpoint ? normalizeProvider(typeof endpoint === "string" ? urlParser(endpoint) : endpoint) : () => getEndpointFromRegion({ ...input,
|       useDualstackEndpoint,

Comment: There is a small mistake in this code. You need to change Body: selectFile to be Body: selectFile[0].